# How can we implement autocomplete with API and multi-select in react-querybuilder?

Tags: reactjs, query-builder, react-query

I am building a search query builder with react-querybuilder and want to fetch the values of certain rules from an API. I also want the values field to be a filter and not just a dropdown, where users can input their filter string and results will appear in the dropdown. If we can make the results as multi-select then it would be better like shown in the image added. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tMHF.png)
I researched on the react-querybuilder and found that it doesn't have the functionality that I'm trying to make.
If anyone from the community can help, please reach out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainer of React Query Builder here. You can achieve this with a custom value editor. The best documentation I have on custom components right now is [here](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/tips/custom-with-fallback). That walks you through creating a custom value editor for dates using [`react-datepicker`](https://reactdatepicker.com/), but the concept would be the same for any other React library.

There are no built-in data fetching features in RQB, so you'd need to build that on your own or use a library, but I would recommend [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/) for its multiselect and async features.

The [RQB home page](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/) actually has a multi-select example using `react-select`. The code for the component itself is [here](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/blob/79d6e437e16d116b1ce7af7af83bc3a91edce73d/website/src/pages/index.tsx#L72-L129) (simplified for brevity below), and usage is [here](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/blob/79d6e437e16d116b1ce7af7af83bc3a91edce73d/website/src/pages/index.tsx#L255).

```
const ExtendedValueEditor_Select = (props: ValueEditorProps) => {
  return (
    <Select
      value={props.value}
      isMulti
      onChange={v => props.handleOnChange(v)}
      options={selectOptions}
    />
  );
};
```

Notes:

- `selectOptions` is an array of type `{ value: string; label: string; }[]`.
- This is almost certainly not the entire value editor you want—please see the ["fallback" docs](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/docs/tips/custom-with-fallback) I mentioned earlier.

To use the component, assign it to `valueEditor` in the `controlElements` prop.

```
<QueryBuilder
  fields={selectFields}
  controlElements={{ valueEditor: ExtendedValueEditor_Select }}
/>
```

Feel free to file issues/discussions on GitHub or join the Discord chat if you have other questions about React Query Builder.

Comment: Hi Jake, Thanks for the all the references and  documentation on how to add a multiselect for the "string" data types.

Comment: However I want to implement autocomplete multiselect only for the "string" datatype fields, other datatype fields should work as they used to before. Implementing the "fallback" for "string" has changed the default behaviour for "date" and "number", can you please guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: @AdityaPol I would need to see your code to determine what the issue is, assuming you followed the guide from the docs. I would recommend continuing this discussion in the RQB Discord chat or GitHub Discussions. You can mark this as the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: sure, @JakeBoone I have taken a look at the github discussions and found a similar use case, I will try to implement that solution.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to mark this question as answered because if my rating.
This was the discussion (https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/discussions/430) I found similar to my case, although there is some issue when I tried to replicate the same code in my application.
The values/options dropdown keeps closing automatically after a second and I'm getting infinite "Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object" errors in the console
can you help ?

Comment: Create a sandbox or sample repo so I can see your code, and submit it as an issue on GH. I'll take a look.

Comment: @AdityaPol Accepting an answer doesn't require reputation, but upvoting an answer does. I believe you may have accidentally pressed the upvote button instead of the accept button, which is the grey tick mark underneath the upvote/downvote buttons.